# Using Mocks inside Doctests?

Tags: python, testing, mocking, python-3.5, doctest

I am using doctests. I am wondering what is the correct way to doctest a function that performs an external action (e.g. sends email, connects to a server, etc)? Using Mock seems like the answer but it will muddy up the doc string of the function.

For example:

```
class SSHConnection(BaseConnection):
    """Provides basic SSH functions.

    >>> host = '127.0.0.1'
    >>> port = 22
    >>> username = 'user'
    >>> password = 'password'
    >>> ssh = SSHConnection(host, username, password, port)
    >>> ssh.execute('uname -a')
    """
...
```

Comment: [*"minimock is a simple library for doing Mock objects with doctest"*](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MiniMock)

Comment: Thanks, I guess I am just confused about making the documentation confusing by introducing Mocks.

Comment: Why not keep simple examples in the docstrings but migrate your actual tests to a proper test runner? Doctests are good for some things but you're evidently reaching the edges of that.

Comment: Yeah that's fair enough! Thanks!