# Mocking in doctests

Tags: python, mocking, doctest

I am writing a Python library that calls on the network. While writing documentation, I would like to provide an example in the form as a doctest:

```
class Endpoint:                                                       
    """RPC endpoint representation for a service.                     

        >>> from ankhor import Endpoint                               
        >>> e = Endpoint("_hello_service._tcp.example.com")                 
        >>> e.say_hello(name="John Doe")
        'hello, John Doe!'                             
        >>>                                                           
    """
```

This obviously fails when running doctests, as the `example.com` domain does not exist. I would like to make this test pass, by mocking out the resolver that the `Endpoint` class uses, and by starting an example service, both before the service starts.

I can obviously use something like this:

```
class Endpoint:                                                       
    """RPC endpoint representation for a service.                     

        >>> from ankhor import Endpoint                               
        >>> from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server             
        >>> import threading     
        >>>                                                                          
        >>> app = hello_world_service.create_app({})                  
        >>> s = make_server('', TEST_PORT, app)                       
        >>> threading.Thread(target=s.handle_request).start()    
        >>>
        >>> e = Endpoint("_hello_service._tcp.example.com", MockedResolver())
        >>> e.say_hello(name="John Doe")                              
        'hello, John Doe!'
        >>>                                                           
    """
```

But this clutters the example code enormously.

So, the ultimate question is: how can I make the cleanness of the first piece of example code, behave like the latter (which mocks out both the service and the discovery)?

Note that this question differs from [Using Mocks inside Doctests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41289247/using-mocks-inside-doctests), where the goal is to use a mock; the goal in this question is to keep the example readable, while still runnable.

Bonus: in the second example, I had to put test classes inside the main Python module tree. It would be nice if they only get loaded when doctests are run.

Comment: Workaround for anyone who'd be stuck on this would be to add `# doctest: +SKIP` at the end of lines that fail on you...